# @ExceptionHandler for jackson's InvalidFormatException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

In a spring-boot application i want to use a general exception handler to capture and handle the `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException`-Exception and return `400` when one is encountered.

Thing is, the exception handler for that exception is not called. Instead a casual 500-error is returned.

What am i missing?
Does this have to do with InvalidFormatException being a nested exception?
How do i fix this?

Code - Exception Handler

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = "packe.path.to.rest.controllers")
public class GeneralExceptionHandler {

   // .. other working exception handlers...

@ExceptionHandler(InvalidFormatException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> processJsonInvalidFormatException(InvalidFormatException e) {
        log.error("Invalid Json Format Exceptioon occurred");

        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        ErrorMessage msg = new ErrorMessage(
            status.value(),
            status.getReasonPhrase(),
            e.getMessage()
        );

        return new ResponseEntity(msg, status);
    }
```

The log shows

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of some.packe.property.A from number value (123): index value outside legal index range [0..2]
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5599410f; line: 2, column: 2] (through reference chain: some.path.to.my.input.body.class["someState"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of path.again... from number value (123): index value outside legal index range [0..2]
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5599410f; line: 2, column: 2] (through reference chain: and.again...)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:208) ~[spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and override the `handleHttpMessageNotReadable` method as follows:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GeneralExceptionHandler {
...
@Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus httpStatus, WebRequest request) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        ErrorMessage msg = new ErrorMessage(
            status.value(),
            status.getReasonPhrase(),
            ex.getMessage()
        );
        return new ResponseEntity(msg, status);
    }
...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = "packe.path.to.rest.controllers")
```

Try just:

```
@ControllerAdvice
```

It looks like the reason may be the exception is thrown in `jackson` packages so, outside your own.

Comment: Ahh i see: correct me, but should it work if add ``com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc`` to the basePackages-parameter?

Comment: I think so. But I usually go for more generic paths like just: `com.fasterxml.jackson`

Comment: Sadly, adding the fasterxml-package does not work. I'll try with an unrestricted Handler then.

Comment: Using a generic @ControllerAdrive-annotated handler does not work either.

Comment: Hum... can you share the full stack trace? The error seems to be relating to parsing something .